# possible cases to find if a shape is encapsulated or not

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

[image: the possible cases i thought off]

For a school project i work on a contour finder with some advanced features. The goal is to make it insane fast and that makes things a little complex sometimes like now.
As i read once "weeks of programming can save hours of thinking", thats hence the topic.

The goal is to find which blobs are totally enclosed by another blob.

An edge pixel is where one pixel is black and the next one is white.

The shape with the red line is the possible parent blob. The condition is that the shape in it get’s totally enclosed by the one with the red line around it. So for **image 0** it’s not a parent blob since it’s open at the top and therefor is not enclosing the other blob.

The blobfinder scans from left to right or top to bottom. The corner pixels get saved. If you would move in the opposite direction from the first pixel stored in a blob you are sure that you would never hit the same blob again. This detail is very important.

Also a contour get’s detected when it goes from a black pixel to a white pixel. So for **image 1**, the inner square get’s detected at the green ellipse, not at the red. In other words, at the green ellipse is where pixel 0, the first pixel is in the pixel array in the blob.

To proceed to our goal, we will scan in the opposite direction of how we did find the contours. So for image 1, we founded the contours by going left to right, to find it’s a enclosed blob we go from right to left.
Also this detail is important.

With every pixel we check, we will also check if the coordinates are outside the possible parent blob. If this condition is true then it’s not an enclosed blob. For example in **image 1**.

If it finds an edge pixel and that coordinate belongs to the blob we where testing then we know it belongs to the possible parent blob, see **image 2**.

If a blob is found that is within the bounds of the one where testing then that blob can be ignored, see **image 3**.

If a blob is found that exceed the bounds of the possible parent blob then we know that the blob where testing is not enclosed by the possible parent blob, see **image 4**.

If a pixel is found from the possible parent blob then we now it’s not an enclosed blob, see **image 5**.

If we know that a blob where testing is a enclosed blob, then all the blobs within the blobs we testing are also enclosed by the possible parent blob, see **image 6**.
(Because of this, it’s good to test bigger blobs before smaller blobs)

My question is, are there any cases that i didn't think off? Or am i wrong in something where a case would fail?
If you can think of something then please provide an image to explain things more visual.
If you have any questions then ask them and i will edit this post to describe it more clear if possible. I already did the best I could.

Comment: Sounds like a nice project - you didn't say how you resolve the blobs once you find a black-to-white transition - connected components (floodfill) and label? Otherwise convex blobs will be problematic. Also consider cases where there is no obvious parent-child, like two interlocking "U" shapes - one inverted, you see what I mean?

Comment: I already have the blobs, i came up with a new algorithm that i call the lemmings algorithm. It's dead simple and insane fast. For the rest, I have every corner of the blob and a method to see if a coordinate is on a edge of a blob.
For the two interlocking "U" shapes, i do a test before to get a hierarchy of containingBlobs where the condition is that blob `a` doesn't intersect with blob `b`.
Thanks for your answer, i will start programming now and hope all goes well :)

Comment: Are you going to share that lemmings algorithm? I bet there would a lot of interest if it's robust and very fast. Good luck anyway, hope all goes well.

Comment: Yes, i want to release it in about 2 months. At the moment it relies on processing, which is like a framework for java. I want to get rid of the frameWork which is kind of easy to do. Also i want to make really good documentation. And i want to visualise the algorithm. There is also some room to make it even faster. And i added some things that makes it a little slower but i prefer to keep that. For example, you can pass a object to it that has a rule to check the threshold. By this it's easy to make your own threshold checker to check only the blue channel for example.

Comment: Here is a preview:
https://vimeo.com/93625089

O yeah, when i release it, do you know a good place to spread the word?

And the reason i came back, i figured n5 is wrong. I have to write a new contour scanner to deal with that which is a lot of work but worth it.
Let me tag you so you get an update,
@RogerRowland

Comment: Forget my OP, i came up with a new algorithm. If i'm correct then it will take around 9 calculations to figure our if a shape is open or not :)
Only downside is that it won't work for shapes with a thickness of 1 pixel.

Comment: Preview looks impressive, so this is intriguing. Post more details if/when you can (or when you feel appropriate) ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55632/discussion-between-clankill3r-and-roger-rowland).